# Как создать объект класса тип таблицы?

Tags: java, ооп

Чтобы можно было ввести данные, типом таблицы в приватный класс table

1 Файл:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;


import edu.san.stats.AverageCalcAware;
import edu.san.stats.MaxMinCalcAware;
import edu.san.stats.MedianCalcAware;
public class IntegerStats implements MaxMinCalcAware , AverageCalcAware , MedianCalcAware {

    private int[] table;

    public void Table(int[]table) {
        this.setTable(table);
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal calcAverage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal calcMedian() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal calcMax() {
        int bd = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<getTable().length; i++){
            if(bd < getTable()[i]) {
                bd = getTable()[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal calcMin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int[] getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(int[] table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

}
```

2 Файл(вывода):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class StatsCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerStats tableint = new IntegerStats();
        tableint.setTable(tableint = {1,2,3,4,5});
        System.out.println(String.format("Max:=", tableint.calcMax()));
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем конкретно ваша проблема?

Comment: с такой формулировкой вам никто не ответит... опишите свою задачу подробно, начиная с исходных данных, заканчивая ожидаемым результатом.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное товарищ спрашивает что

```
int [] outTable =  tableint.getTable();
outTable[3] = 33; // вводи данные 

 tableint.getTable()[5] =  25 // или даже так
```

Comment: если это правильный ответ, то я тоже хочу на эти курсы экстрасенсов...